# Is there any git option to automatically merge commits from master branch into a feature branch?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have a feature branch in git that needs to be up to date with the master branch at all times. Is there any way to automatize this in git? I basically want on every commit in master branch a merge into feature branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a server-side `update` hook to do this merge whenever someone pushes new commits to `master`.  See the [relevant section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) of *Pro Git* for an overview.

Now, I would submit to you that the presence of this requirement indicates a problem with your development workflow, since the whole point of a "feature branch" is that you develop the feature independently, and then merge it into your mainline development branch later.  But, I don't know anything about your workflow or what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, so it's really up to you to decide if this is something you'd really need to do (or if it is actually a good idea or not).

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no command in Git to do such thing automatically. The
only way is to create a separate program or add an entry to crontab
that would periodically fetch changes from master and inform you that
new changes are available so that you could merge them into your
feature branch.